# Best practice for crash reporting in C# my application

Tags: c#, frameworks, crash-reports

I need to implement crash reporting framework on my C#(WPF) application, so i need full call stack,What would you guys suggest for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx)

```
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
        for(int i =0; i< st.FrameCount; i++ )
        {
            // Note that high up the call stack, there is only
            // one stack frame.
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(i);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("High up the call stack, Method: {0}",
                sf.GetMethod());

            Console.WriteLine("High up the call stack, Line Number: {0}",
                sf.GetFileLineNumber());
        }
```

Comment: Probably better to log in a file , instead of console .

Comment: I am just showing how to get stack trace Ankur, it is not real apllication